# What causes java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in running code

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

This error : `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : javax.xml.soap.SoapException`

I can see javax.xml.soap.SoapException is on the classpath so what could be causing this error ?

In more general terms how could a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` be thrown in running code, should the compiler not catch this error ? The only situation I could this occurring is that if a jar was built using a library and the library that jar depends on is not on the classpath when using the jar.

Comment: Is it really looking for javax.xml.soap.soapexception? Because that class doesn't exist. javax.xml.soap.SoapException, does exist, however.

Comment: It means the class is not found.  It may be that the class exists somewhere in the execution environment, but not in the classpath that was being accessed at the time of the error.

Comment: If a component of the app attempts to use a custom class loader to load a class and the class is not found in that loader's path you can get this error, even if the class is in the main classpath.

Comment: @rmlan it should be [`javax.xml.soap.SOAPException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPException.html)

Comment: It's definitely `SOAPException` for Java.  .NET has a class called `SoapException` - maybe that's where the confusion has come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath you use to compile an app, is not the same as the classpath you use to run the application.  When an application is run using java you still need to have the -cp to load all the supporting jars

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
Class.forName("this.will.throw.ClassNotFoundException")
```